# jre-6u29-windows-i586 installation is blocking?

Tags: java

when i am trying to install `jre-6u29-windows-i586`. I am not able to install that software instead it is showing a dialogue  box current installation causes some changes in user setting  with dialogue header user access control ..how to resolve this problem.

Comment: 1) This is unintelligible.  2) The subject matter is off-topic.  Questions about how to install software don't belong here.

Comment: (Aside: why are you installing an ancient version of Java?  You realise ... I hope ... that it will be riddled with security flaws.)

Comment: Klick OK, it is the Windows User Access Controll. This dialogs will be shown, for nearly every installation. Just ensure, that you gat an official Java-Installer. And. Java 6is out of suppert. Use Java 7 instead.

Comment: [UAC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/User_Account_Control) - either you do not have permissions to install software on that computer or, worse, you are asking which of two buttons you should press.

Comment: its condition from my work environment.No option for me to go for java 7 .And if click on yes it is not showing any dialogue box it is just being quite

Comment: i know we need to press 'yes' .